# Leibniz Integral Rule, proving independence of time

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently attempting this question:

Prove that $Q(t)$ is independent of time.

$Q = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}u^{2} dx $, with
$\frac{\partial{u}} {\partial{t}} + u\frac{\partial{u}} {\partial{x}} = 0 $ 
($u = u(x,t)$)

What I have attempted so far:

$\frac{\partial{u}} {\partial{t}} = - u\frac{\partial{u}} {\partial{x}}$ (*)

$\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}u^{2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial{u^{2}}} {\partial{t}} dx $

I am not so sure afterwards how to proceed, I inputted the property from (*), does it then make

$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial{u^{2}}} {\partial{t}} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -u\frac{\partial{u^{2}}} {\partial{x}} dx$?

I know that ultimately I will need $\frac{dE}{dt} = 0$.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative to $t$ of $u^2$ is $2 u \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ by the chain rule. So,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} E}{\text{d} t} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t)^2\,\text{d} x = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2u \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\text{d} x.
\end{equation}
If you now use the PDE that $u$ satisfies, you can actually calculate the integral by recognising the integrand as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(- \frac{1}{3} u^3\right)$. Now you only need to argue that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u(x,t)^3 = 0$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial{u^{2}}} {\partial{t}} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -u\frac{\partial{u^{2}}} {\partial{x}} dx
=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx
=-\frac{1}{3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial u^3}{\partial x}dx=0,
$$
if $u$ goes to zero at infinity.